# How to check if file exists in a folder in my project in Visual Studio solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, path, projects-and-solutions

I have a folder created in my Project. In my code I want to determine if a file exists in that folder. How can I do that ?

**----------
EDIT:**

I'll try to put the question in a different way.

I have an mvc 4 project that has all of the startup folders : Controllers, Views, Models etc. I have added another folder in my project called `MyResources` . In that folder I have added few pdf files. In one of my controllers i have a logics that has to check if the passed name of file exists in that particular folder. Lets say that I have passed `PassedFileName.pd` and I want to check if that file is available in the `MyResources` folder. I have tried with the `System.IO.File.Exists(@"~/MyResources/PassedFileName.pdf")` but it always returns `false`.
When I right-click on the file itself( in the solution explorer) and see what is its actual path it says: `C:\(phisical-path-on-my-machine)\MyProjectName\Resources\ReturnHelpPdf.pdf` . That makes me think that I need the path to my project somehow so I can `string.Format` it. I hope that you understand what are my concerns. I know how to check if file exists on the File system. But here I have to make check for something I am not complete sure if I have the full information about.

Comment: What are you trying to do that you want your running code to check a folder in your visuial studio project? Unless you are writing a plugin for visual studio your code should not care what the project looks like.

Comment: When your code is running nobody knows what's your project structure. So you can't. If you're talking about just to check file exists in path or not there are already so many answers readily available for you.

Comment: What is the project type?

Comment: @Damith It is MVC4 project.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `var fileExists = File.Exists(path);` to check if a file exists at a given path
if the file exists, the variable `fileExists` will be `true` else it is `false`.

Of course you can also check directly in a if statement

```
if(File.Exists(path))
{
    ....
}
else { ... }
```

Comment: I can only get the relative path and it always returns false. I was wondering how to get the absolute path to the file so I can do File.Exists(full_path)

Comment: Do you know the "real directory"? If you do, you can use `Path.Combine` like this: `var absolute_path = Path.Combine(prefix, relative path);` if you want to get the full path with the "..." collapsed, use `Path.GetFullPath((new Uri(absolute_path)).LocalPath);`

Answer (score 3):

**Problem :** you need to provide the valid `physical path` of the file. to check with `File.Exists()` method.

**Solution :** you need to use the `Server.MapPath()` function to get the valid `physical Path` of the given `relative path`.

Try This:

```
 String path=Server.MapPath(@"~/MyResources/PassedFileName.pdf");
 if(File.Exists(path))
 {
  //File Found

 }
```

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: yes, i have seen the edit after posting my anser now edited again, thanks for your remainder :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`File.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to check a file exists on a path. This is available in the `System.IO` namespace.

```
string filePath= @"c:\Projects\sample.txt";
if(File.Exists(filePath))
{
  //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Programatically you can use the `System.IO.File.Exists()` or `System.IO.Directory.Exists()` methods

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the `~\` path you need to use the function [HttpServerUtility.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
System.IO.File.Exists(HttpServerUtility.MapPath(@"~/MyResources/PassedFileName.pdf"))
```

What `MapPath` will do is turn the `~\` in to the path that your project is currently running on the IIS server.

Answer (score 0):

Usualy Folders inside a Visual Studio Solution, are for organization purpose, and they don't exist in the file system. Since the Visual Studio Solution file has XML on it, you can load the file and with XPath, find the location of the folder, and if it has any files in it.

You can create only the solution, a folder, and add a file to it, and check inside the XML how Visual Studio store that information.

Answer (score 0):

If you alredy know the file name then use

```
if(File.Exist("File path"))
{
}
```

If you want to check if any file exist within that folder then use

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("Directory Path");
if(files.Length > 0)
{
//File exist
}
```